# Error RVIZ extrapolation into the future on the same machine

Tags: ros, rviz

I get the following error when trying to view my [RPLidar](https://github.com/babakhani/rplidar_ros2) A2 scan in rviz2. It’s on a differential drive robot controlled using Odrive and ros2 control using [Articulated](https://github.com/joshnewans/articubot_one/tree/humble) Robotics. I am running everything on a laptop, no separate machines, on ROS2 humble. (BTW when I run the lidar and odrive on RPI the error get more often).

It shows perfectly fine when viewing the base_link frame, but with Odom the issue occurs.

The error:

```
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1681401743.264000589] [rviz2]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1681401743.323050 but the latest data is at time 1681401743.259460, when looking up transform from frame [laser_frame] to frame [map]
```

I changed the RPlidar pkg according this [link](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24036/lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future-on-the-same-machine), Lookup would require extrapolation into the future on the same machine. It works intermittently but it often loses transform (I often get the error).

i tried to change the update_rate in the controller.yaml for ros2 control, but the issue just get wors.

Comment: Have you checked resource usage of the system? I'm fairly confident you're hitting a bottleneck, either with CPU processing the pointcloud data, or you're I/O bound on the LIDAR input.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i did not see any issue, moreover, i conected  the USB just RPlidar on strong computer. RPLidar should work on RPI so not sure about that. BTW, the TF should wait to the data? Keep in mind that once i set the fix frame to base frame all work good, no issue at all...

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix the issue, i changed the publish rate in rplidar file (rplidar_node.cpp), from 1ms to 100ms and now all good. the change should be hardcode in file

Comment: Any explanation on why this works would be great to all future viewers of your answer.